# Write CSV in HDFS

Tags: r, csv, hadoop

I wrote the following function to write data in HDFS using R and am using rhdfs.

```
writeToHDFS <- function(fileName){
   hdfs.init()
   modelfile <- hdfs.file(fileName, "w")
   hdfs.write(get(fileName), modelfile)
   hdfs.close(modelfile)
}
```

How do I modify it store this data in CSV format instead?I have tried using `pipe` but since it is deprecated, I would like a way to write CSV files through hdfs.write functions.

I tried this:

```
   modelfile <- hdfs.file(paste(fileName, "csv", sep="."), "w")
```

but I do not think it creates a valid CSV but only appends the extension for it.